# How to correct cell's value displaying using Google visualization

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am linking a Google spreadsheet to display some values in HTML pointing to row index and column index in the spreadsheet.  Value in round brackets:

> Abolenkin, Andrei (0,2)

It works, but after editing, sorting, adding new rows in correspondent Google spreadsheet a cells values are swapping with wrong or empty cells:

> Abolenkin, Andrei (0,0)

The question is how to properly point to and fix the values of the linked cells?

Please look at [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tTfV1DwfbipOvCMGMhekNIDRVDROwhrvofjA5YE2JHY/edit#gid=0) and the code below

```js
// https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var spreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tTfV1DwfbipOvCMGMhekNIDRVDROwhrvofjA5YE2JHY/edit#gid=0range=A";
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
        // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#methods
        // getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        
        document.getElementById("Abolenkin").innerHTML = dataTable.getFormattedValue(0, 0);
        document.getElementById("Akhmadullina").innerHTML = dataTable.getFormattedValue(1, 0);
       var date = (new Date().getFullYear()).toString();
       document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
      }
```

```css
/* Indexmod CSS */


/* Лого */

.header {
padding:0px;
margin:30;
}

/* Страница */

.content {
 padding: 20px;
 margin: auto;
 font: 20px Georgia, serif;
 line-height: 27px;
}

h1 {
font-size:70px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:100;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type:none
}

a:link    {color:black; text-decoration:none}
a:visited {color:black; text-decoration:none}
a:hover   {color:black; text-decoration:underline}
a:active  {color:black; text-decoration:none}

/* Подвал */

.footer {
 margin: auto;
}


#year {

    vertical-align: super;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;

}

.what {

    vertical-align: super;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    
}

.name {

    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<main class="content">

     
         <p id="Abolenkin-Andrei"> <span class=name>Abolenkin, Andrei</span> (<span id="Abolenkin"></span><a class=what href="http://www.indexmod.info/indexmod" title="Based on the Indexmod algorithm. Click for more info.">?</a>), Andrei Abolenkin; A.K.A Nekto Abolenkin; Rus. Андрей Аболенкин; Некто Аболенкин; born 1972, Moscow, is a Russian style and fashion expert, consultant and promoter. <a href="http://sites.google.com/site/indexmodencyclopedia/abolenkin-andrei"> Login to edit entire article indexmod.info/abolenkin-andrei</a></p>
    
    <p id="Akhmadullina-Alena"> <span class=name>Akhmadullina, Alena</span> (<span id="Akhmadullina"></span><a class=what href="http://www.indexmod.info/indexmod" title="Based on the Indexmod algorithm. Click for more info.">?</a>), Rus. Алёна Ахмадуллина, born 1978, Sosnovy Bor, Leningrad Oblast, is a Russian fashion designer, founder of the brand Alena Akhmadullina, participant of various Russian and international competitions in the field of fashion, мember of “Snob” from April 2009.</p>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the spreadsheet is sorted, then cannot guarantee the values needed are on rows 0 and 1 respectively

`dataTable.getFormattedValue(0, 0)  //<-- (row, column)`

to ensure the correct value is found, you can use the [`getFilteredRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows) method on the DataTable

see the `findValue` function in the following working snippet,
a Table chart is used to help visualize the problem

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var spreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tTfV1DwfbipOvCMGMhekNIDRVDROwhrvofjA5YE2JHY/edit#gid=0range=A";
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var dataTable = response.getDataTable();

  //var container = document.getElementById("chart_div");
  //var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  //chart.draw(dataTable);

  document.getElementById("Abolenkin").innerHTML = findValue("Abolenkin");
  document.getElementById("Akhmadullina").innerHTML = findValue("Akhmadullina");

  function findValue(surname) {
    var value = '';

    var rowsFound = dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 7,
      value: surname
    }]);

    if (rowsFound.length > 0) {
      value = dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowsFound[0], 0);
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div>
  Abolenkin: <span id="Abolenkin"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Akhmadullina: <span id="Akhmadullina"></span>
</div>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! When I remove <span id="chart_div"></span> function stop working. Please clear how to hide table from html?